# django combine multiple ListView using get_query and search form

Tags: python, django, listview, search, filter

in my project, I have three models

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=75, verbose_name='Tag')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='tags', blank=True)
```

and I created search filter view in **views.py**

```
def is_valid_queryparam(param):
    return param != '' and param is not None

class SearchPepsiView(ListView):
    template_name = "blog/NewSearch.html"
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchPepsiView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['category'] = Post.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['category'])
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        qs = Post.objects.all()
        categories = Category.objects.filter(parent=None).order_by('name')
        PostOrAuthor_query = request.GET.get('PostOrAuthor')
        SearchCategory_query = request.GET.get('SearchCategory')

        if is_valid_queryparam(PostOrAuthor_query):
            qs = qs.filter(Q(title__icontains=PostOrAuthor_query) |
                           Q(content__icontains=PostOrAuthor_query) |
                           Q(author__username__icontains=PostOrAuthor_query)).distinct()

        if is_valid_queryparam(SearchCategory_query) and SearchCategory_query != 'Choose...':
            qs = qs.filter(category__name=SearchCategory_query)

        count = qs.count() or 0

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'queryset': qs,
            'categories': categories,
            'count': count,
        })
```

and I created Post Per Category View in **views.py**

```
class PostPerCategoryCBV(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/Category_Projects.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.category = Category.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return Post.objects.filter(category=self.category)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostPerCategoryCBV, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category'] = self.category
        return context
```

and I created Post Per Tag View in **views.py**

```
class PostPerTagCBV(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/tag_projects.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        qs = qs.filter(tags__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return qs
```

and in templates, I created **NewSearch.html**

```
<form class="col-12 mt-5 mb-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Post or Author</label>
                    <input type="search" name="PostOrAuthor" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Post or Author">
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="SearchCategory">Category</label>
                        <select id="SearchCategory" name="SearchCategory" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                            {% for cat in categories %}
                                <option value="{{ cat.name }}">{{ cat.name }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-12">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <p>You have<b> {{ count }} </b>search results </p>
        </div>
        {% if category %}
            <div class="row">
                {% for post in category %}
                    {% include 'blog/Post_Loop.html' %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="row">
                {% for post in queryset %}
                    {% include 'blog/Post_Loop.html' %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

and Here is my **URLs.py**

```
path('post_list/', PostListCBV.as_view(), name='list-post'),
path("search-pepsi/", SearchPepsiView.as_view(), name="search-pepsi"),
path('tags_projects/<str:slug>/', PostPerTagCBV.as_view(), name='tag-posts'),
path('category_posts/<str:slug>/', SearchPepsiView.as_view(), name='category-posts'),
```

**My success:**

When all search fields are empty .. it list all posts.

when entering any search query .. it backs with the search result.

**my problem is:**

I believe that there are someway I can combine ListView of Post_Per_Category and Post_Per_Tag with Search View (in ONE View and one template) .. so I created `def get_queryset(self):` to use it but it didn't worked.

Anybody can help please ...

Thanks in-advance